# dpkg-deb, how can I specify the architecture

Tags: dpkg, packaging, debian, ppc64le

I am trying to create a debian package for my software which needs to be installed on a power machine. The output of `uname -a` on the power machine is:

`ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux`

I already have the debian package for amd64 architecure which I create using the dpkg-deb command.
How can I specify the architecure in the dpkg-deb command to resolve this? Or is there a better way to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind. Found the solution.
In the DEBIAN/control file, you need to provide the architecture as follows: 
`Version: ppc64el`
and it runs fine on my Power machine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: That won't work: you need to recompile to PPC too!  PPC processors are not instruction compatible with AMD_64 instructions.

Comment: If an answer doesn't work, DV it

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you shouldn't use "Version: ppc64el", but "Architecture: ppc64el" if this is a software for ppc64el only. You can also use "Architecture: any" if your software is able to build on any architecture you try to build it.